# How to avoid duplicate mysql insert

Tags: php, mysql

I am asking about handling a high traffic. So, here is the case.

I am building an auction system. Each bid will have a record by using

```
       ///make sure time should more than next bid [there are delay on each bidding]
    if($waktu < $arrAuction['nextBid']){
        $objWaktu = new \DateTime($waktu);
        $objNextBid = new \DateTime($arrAuction['nextBid']);
        $objNextBid->diff($objWaktu);
        $minute = $objNextBid->format("i");
        return array('status'=>'failed','notification'=>getStr('auctionNext',array($minute)));
    }        

    ///insert bid
    $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO $tableAuctionBid(bidId,auctionId,userId,bid,waktu) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
    $process = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $process->bind_param('sssds',$bidId,$auctionId,$member['uniqueKey'],$bid,$waktu);
    $process->execute();
    if($conn->affected_rows == 0){
        return array('status'=>'failed','notification'=>getStr('strinvalid',array('bidId system')));
    }
    $process->close();

    ///modify next bid
    $getValue = new \main\core\getValue();
    $bidTime = $getValue->settings(single:'nextBidTime');
    $nextBid = new \DateTime($waktu);
    $nextBid->modify('+ '.$bidTime.' minute');
    $nextBid = $nextBid->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    ///update last bidder
    $sql = "UPDATE $tableAuction SET lastBidder=?,currentBid=?,nextBid=? WHERE auctionId=?";
    $process = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $process->bind_param('sdss',$member['uniqueKey'],$bid,$nextBid,$auctionId);
    $process->execute();
    $process->close();
```

So, each new bid will update "next bid time" in the auction listing. User cannot bid after there are another bid placed. [ > 5 minutes waiting time ]

However, I am so curious how if there are multiple users bid in the same time? Will those data's inserted?

Comment: MySQL will queue multiple attempts to do the same thing, Thats why you are using a half decent DBMS and not Access

Comment: You should use a transaction to make multiple queries atomic.

Comment: @Barmar I am currently reading this page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html. Is it correct reference?

Comment: No try this one https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php

Comment: You could save yourself some effort by using an After Insert trigger on the Bids table to update the Next Bid Time on the auctions table.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Thank you! Anyway, is it referred to this source? https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/mysql-after-insert-trigger/

Comment: @bobby That's one possible reference.